# How to disable version 1 and version 2c in snmpd?

Tags: snmp, snmpd

Because I just use snmp v3 and want to disable version 1 and version 2c in snmpd.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Comment out the lines that start with `com2sec`, `group`, and `access` in snmpd.conf, e.g:

```
 [root@sandbox snmp]# cat snmpd.conf
 #com2sec notConfigUser  default       public
 #group   notConfigGroup v1           notConfigUser
 #group   notConfigGroup v2c           notConfigUser
 view    systemview    included   .1.3.6.1.2.1.1
 view    systemview    included   .1.3.6.1.2.1.25.1.1
 #access  notConfigGroup ""      any       noauth    exact  systemview none none
 #com2sec local     0.0.0.0/0        publicrw
 #com2sec mynetwork 0.0.0.0/0        publicro
 #group MyRWGroup  any        local
 #group MyROGroup  any        mynetwork
 view all    included  .1                               80
 view mib2   included  .iso.org.dod.internet.mgmt.mib-2 fc
 #access MyROGroup ""      any       noauth    0      all    none   none
 #access MyRWGroup ""      any       noauth    0      all    all    all
 syslocation Unknown (edit /etc/snmp/snmpd.conf)
 syscontact Root <root@localhost> (configure /etc/snmp/snmp.local.conf)
 rwuser readonly

[root@sandbox snmp]# snmpwalk -v1 -c public localhost
Timeout: No Response from localhost

[root@sandbox snmp]# snmpwalk -v2c -c public localhost
Timeout: No Response from localhost

[root@sandbox snmp]# snmpwalk -v 3 -n '' -l authPriv -u "readonly" -A "readonly" -X "readonly" localhost IF-MIB::ifName
IF-MIB::ifName.1 = STRING: lo 
IF-MIB::ifName.2 = STRING: eth0
IF-MIB::ifName.3 = STRING: eth1
```

Answer (score 1):

> it's good to run `snmpwalk` tests from **chocripple** answer before and after disabling v1, v2 https://serverfault.com/a/376693/460967

A **simple solution**:

1. stop the SNMP daemon
2. rename (move) snmpd.conf (the default config has v1, v2 enabled)
3. create an SNMPv3 user, e.g. a r/o user (it will create a new snmpd.conf with SNMPv3 only)
4. enable & start the SNMP daemon

```bash
systemctl stop snmpd
mv /etc/snmp/snmpd.conf /etc/snmp/snmpd.conf.orig
net-snmp-create-v3-user -ro -a SHA -x AES <myv3user>
systemctl enable snmpd
systemctl start snmpd
systemctl status snmpd
```

5. (optionally) run `snmpwalk` tests to make sure that v1, v2 are off and v3 works.